# Where to find glossy background images for UIButton?

Tags: ios, user-interface, graphics, uibutton

I want to have a glossy button in my iPhone app (in the style of the black toolbar). However, as you all know, those are not included in the SDK.

So I wonder if anyone knows where to get ready to use button images.

I have of course googled for that, but I could not find any useful graphics. My requirements to button graphics are:

- should match Apple's style used in the black toolbar / titlebar
- should have resolution high enough for retina devices
- should be available for commercial use (does not need to be free)

I have also taken a look at some programmatic solutions like Michael Heyeck's [Shiny Red Buttons](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?page_id=372) which are quite well done. However I would prefer to have a simple png file to use as a button background image.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the link [here](http://maniacdev.com/2010/07/cre/) - it might help    .

Comment: Thanks for the link. This looks interesting. However this solution also requires programming and I could not figure out how to use the ButtonMaker app. Maybe the `UIGlassButton class is no longer included in iOS 6... So: +1 but not the solution I was looking for.